# How to find whether the disk is thin provisioned or not?

Tags: windows, powershell, iscsi, thin-provisioning

I have mapped IScsi volumes into my windows 2016 server. I have created disk out of them. Now i need to find whether the disk is thin provisioned or not.

I am trying with below cmdlets

> Get-Disk and Get-PhysicalDisk

But no luck. How to find whether the disk is thin provisioned or not using powershell?

Comment: What makes you think you can find this information out from the client-side?

Comment: @Chopper3 Windows will happily tell you [in the GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aEak8.png). Why not in PowerShell?

Comment: For an iSCSI-shared drive mount? It'll tell you for locally-attached volumes obviously but are you sure?

Comment: There should be some indication, because on newer versions of windows the `defrag` command does different things for thinly-provisioned storage, and as far as I know it does correctly handle iSCSI connected storage devices when deciding what to do.

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn or, `Optimize-Volume` in PowerShell.

Comment: @Chopper3 Why not? The iSCSI target generally [reports that information](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/storage/thin-provisioning) to the initiator.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I actually didn't know about that cmdlet, thanks for the info!

Answer (score 6):

This is wrong command. You need to traverse back your mount point to iSCSI name/ address etc and query target with this name in mind.

Get-IscsiVirtualDisk cmdlet is what you need.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/iscsitarget/Get-IscsiVirtualDisk

Comment: Is this for Server 2016 only? I can't find this cmdlet on Windows 10. (and I don't have a Server 2016 VM handy...)

Comment: Well it ways "Windows 10" as well so I guess it *should* work. I only tried Windows Server 2016 myself...